# Make object consistently move with wasd in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a kind of rocket ship game and I'm having trouble with the movement. This is the code for the moving:

```js
function moveSelection(evt) {
  element = document.getElementById("base");
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 68:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 87:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 83:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
  }
  element = document.getElementById("base2");
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 68:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 87:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 83:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
```

When the key is pressed, it moves the two elements which make up my ship. However, on my pc, the ship moves once, there is a delay, and then it starts moving more. I would like it to be moving the whole time that the key is pressed down.

Also, it would be cool if I could make it smooth and not jump along in groups of 10px (though still at the same speed)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please also post HTML and CSS too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9s13tqgz/
@AliDemirci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is actually what you want.

It moves smoothly and does not get caught up by vacuum of space.

You'll have to figure out how to handle sticky keys yourself since SO is not a code-for-me platform.

Good luck.

```js
var element;
var inter;
function moveSelection(evt) {
  if(inter) {
    clearTimeout(inter);
  }
  
  inter = setInterval(move, 10, evt)
}

function move(evt) {  
  element = document.getElementById("base");
  
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 68:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 87:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 83:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
  }
  
  element = document.getElementById("base2");
  
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 68:
      element.style.left = (parseInt(element.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 87:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) - 10) + 'px';
      break;
    case 83:
      element.style.top = (parseInt(element.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
      break;
  }
}

function moving(evt) {
  clearInterval(inter)
  inter = null;
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
window.addEventListener('keyup', moving);
```

```css
body{
  background: #120349;
}
#base {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

#base::before {
  border-bottom: 60px solid darkgrey;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  width: 0;
}

#base::after {
  border-bottom: 120px solid #FFA300;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#base2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #272727;
  z-index: 1;
}

#base2::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="base" name="char" style="top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute;"></div>
<div id="base2" name="char" style="top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just checking, because I want to know how it works, is the only thing you did adding the ```inter = null``` line of code?

Comment: Not only that. See moveSelection function. There’s a check which clears interval if there’s already running one. That avoids intervals stacking.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `keydown` event. Which will only occur when a key is pressed although can repeat.
What may make more sense for "smooth" movement would be to use a regular timeout, that moves the ship.

Create a timeout - `setInterval` when the keydown event is received. The function called by the interval will move the ship (so a different one for each direction). Store the handle (id) this returns in a variable like "currentShipInterval".

When a keyup event, or new keydown is received, use clearInterval with that ID to remove it.

Comment: I'd actually use a setInterval which is initialized onkeydown and terminated onkeyup. The function invoked every `x` ms would move the ship.

Comment: Presumably, you'd still store the handle for the setInterval in a variable - but yes - that is cleaner.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ban2rue5/ is what I have right now.

This works well, but if I hold down the key for too long then it creates multiple instances of the interval so the rocket starts moving really quickly and can't be stopped.

Comment: Hello there, I mentioned that a new keydown should use clearInterval to remove the last interval - otherwise I'd expect them to stack up that way.